# How can I read from unmanaged memory in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, unmanaged

I'd like to create `Foo` objects in C# from an unmanaged array of `Foo` structs created in C++.
This is how I think it should work:

On the C++ side:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* createFooDetector()
{
    return new FooDetector();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void releaseFooDetector(void* fooDetector)
{
    FooDetector *fd = (FooDetector*)fooDetector;
    delete fd;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int detectFoo(void* fooDetector, Foo **detectedFoos)
{
    FooDetector *fd = (FooDetector*)fooDetector;
    vector<Foo> foos;
    fd->detect(foos);

    int numDetectedFoos = foos.size();
    Foo *fooArr = new Foo[numDetectedFoos];
    for (int i=0; i<numDetectedFoos; ++i)
    {
        fooArr[i] = foos[i];
    }

    detectedFoos = &fooArr;

    return numDetectedFoos;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void releaseFooObjects(Foo* fooObjects)
{
    delete [] fooObjects;
}
```

On C# side:
(I ommitted some fancy code making it possible to call the C++ functions from within C# for better readability);

```
List<Foo> detectFooObjects()
{
    IntPtr fooDetector = createFooDetector();

    IntPtr detectedFoos = IntPtr.Zero;
    detectFoo(fooDetector, ref detectedFoos);

    // How do I get Foo objects from my IntPtr pointing to an unmanaged array of Foo structs?

    releaseFooObjects(detectedFoos);

    releaseFooDetector(fooDetector);
}
```

But I don't know how to retrieve the objects from the `IntPtr detectedFoos`. It should be possible somehow...
Any hints?

**UPDATE**

Let's assume, `Foo` is a simple detection rectangle.

C++:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
};
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Foo
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;
}
```

Is it possible to read from unmanaged memory and create new managed objects from it before releasing the unmanaged memory?

I don't know how may `Foo` objects will be detected, so I don't know, how much memory to allocate in C# before calling `detectFoo()`. That's why I alloc/free memory in C++ and just pass a pointer to it. But somehow I can't retrieve the `detectedFoo`s pointer address under C#. How do I do that?

Comment: This is not going to go anywhere.  You can get a pointer to a Foo but that doesn't help you all.  You don't know what the layout of a Foo object looks like.  Only a C++ compiler knows.  You'll need to write a wrapper class in the C++/CLI language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by using a C++/CLI wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

You must re-declare `Foo` in your C# project. Assuming you know the count of `Foo`s and the value of `sizeof(Foo)` you should be able to use `System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to retrieve your `Foo` structures one at a time.

Comment: I don't know how many `Foo`s will be detected. So `System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal.PtrToStructure()` is not an option, I guess?

Comment: You must return the number of `Foo`. Nobody can do anything to a pointer of an array of unknown size.

Comment: detectFoo() returns the number of detected Foos. Doesn't it?

Comment: @DeadMG: Of course I know how many Foos were detected, I return that value .. I just forgot it in my code above. What I don't know: the number of objects BEFORE calling the method. So I can't alloc memory in C# on beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your struct again in C#, and it depends on your stuct. Your struct have to be blitable (the memory layout of the C# struct ave to be the same as it is for the C struct)

Have a look at "Marshalling structs"

Or post your real "Foo" struct and i can show you the C# version

**UPDATE:**

Because your struct seems to be blitable, you can simple cast the pointer to unmanaged memory to a pointer to the struct defined in c#:

If it is ok for your application to use unsafe code you can write:

```
unsafe List<Foo> detectFooObjects()
{
 List<Foo> res = new List<Foo>()
IntPtr fooDetector = createFooDetector();

IntPtr detectedFoos = IntPtr.Zero;
int nNumFoos = detectFoo(fooDetector, ref detectedFoos );
for(int i=0;i<nNumFoos;i++)
{
   Foo** ppDetectedFoos = detectedFoos.ToPointer();

   Foo* pFoo = *ppDetectedFoos
   res.Add(*pFoo); //copies the struct because is a struct
   ppDetectedFoos++:
}

releaseFooObjects(detectedFoos);

releaseFooDetector(fooDetector);
return res;
}
```